# What's the systemctl equivalent for a command like 'chkconfig --level 5 iptables on'

Tags: linux, systemd, chkconfig

I know `systemctl enable iptables` is similar to the command `chkconfig --level 5 iptables on`, but both are not exactly same.

Using `systemctl`, how do we restrict a service to be started only on a given target like graphical.target.

Answer (score 4):

That's what the `WantedBy=` and `RequiredBy=` directives in `systemd` unit files are for:

From [`man systemd.unit`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#WantedBy=):

> WantedBy=, RequiredBy=
>
> This option may be used more than once, or a space-separated list of unit names may be given. A symbolic link is created in the .wants/ or .requires/ directory of each of the listed units when this unit is installed by systemctl enable. This has the effect that a dependency of type Wants= or Requires= is added from the listed unit to the current unit. The primary result is that the current unit will be started when the listed unit is started. See the description of Wants= and Requires= in the [Unit] section for details.

So the symbolic link created is what causes `systemd` to start the given unit when the target/unit is started.

---

So for example:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Would cause the unit to only be started when `graphical.target` is run (if the unit is enabled).

---

Another example:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=my-custom-target.target graphical.target
```

Would cause the unit to be started when `my-custom-target.target` or `graphical.target` is run (if the unit is enabled).

---

One final thing to keep in mind, it can be difficult to restrict things to a single target because some targets depend on others. For example, `graphical.target` `Requires=multi-user.target`, so when `graphical.target` is started all units from `multi-user.target` are also started. Just keep in mind that some targets are built up on top of others, and that the ones built on top will get everything from the targets they depend on.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct equivalency to `chkconfig --level 5 iptables on`. It does not make sense and is confusing to continue thinking in terms of the old sysvinit. **There is no such thing as a runlevel in systemd.**

That said.. you can ask the service manager to start iptables only when graphical.target is reached by using WantedBy=graphical.target in the service's [Install] section.